# Autowired not working with TestNG Test Class

Tags: spring, testng

I am unable to access an autowired class (ListService) located in a test class.  Outside of the test, I can successfully access the autowired class to make the following call:

> List schoolSubjectList =
>   listService.getMathSubjectList();

The above call results in a null pointer exception.

Test Class:

```
...
@Autowired
ListService listService;

@BeforeClass
public void setUp(ITestContext context) throws Exception {
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomInteger = Math.abs(random.nextInt(1000));

    suiteParams = context.getSuite().getXmlSuite().getAllParameters();

    List<SchoolSubjectDto> schoolSubjectList = listService.getMathSubjectList();
    int sizeOfSchoolSubjectList = schoolSubjectList.size();

    ...
```

Comment: Does your test class implement `AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests`? That would be responsible for the autowiring.

Comment: See http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/testng-spring-integration-example/ as well for a nice complete example?

Comment: @AlexandreFillatre Your answer worked for me. Please post it as an answer. That will be helpful for the community.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure your class implements `AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests`.

For a full example, see [mkyong.com/unittest/testng-spring-integration-example](http://mkyong.com/unittest/testng-spring-integration-example)